# Linking 2 jForms with a button - java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton, actionlistener

I have 2 `JForms` in my project and I'm attempting to link one to the other with a button so once the button is click it display the `JForm`, my forms are called;

`home` and `store`

This is my code so far;

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    storeform = new store();
    form.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have 2 JForms in my project and I'm attempting to link one to the
>   other with a button so once the button is click it display the JForm,
>   my forms are called;

- use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead of two JForms, read linked Oracle tutorial for working code example
- call `JFrame.pack()` after card is switched

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    store form = new store();
    form.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here the solution of your problem:

in your code there is a syntax error that **storeform** should be written as **store form** otherwise it is correct.